# cuda out of memory while trying to train a model with Transformer model of spacy

Tags: pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train a custom NER model on top of Spacy transformer model.
For faster training, I'm running it on a GPU with cuda on Google Colab Pro with High-Ram server.

After the first iteration, I get an error:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 480.00 MiB (GPU 0;
> 11.17 GiB total capacity; 9.32 GiB already allocated; 193.31 MiB free; 10.32 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

For the above error I tried emptying cache too. But still I'm getting this error. Seems like it’s not freeing up enough space.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Moreover I also tried reducing the batch sizes even to 2. Still the same error occurs.

Comment: check gpu allocation using `nvidia-smi`

Comment: check out this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378188/14125950)